# Sharebutton.to showing up as one of my pages

Tags: google-analytics

When I look at **Behavior** -> **Site Content** -- it shows that /sharebutton.to is one of my most popular pages and i have to idea why.

I have done some research and have found how to remove sharebutton.to as a referal link, but I have not found anything on why google analytics thinks that /sharebutton.to is one of my pages.

If you actually go to the link coloriddistribution/com/sharebutton.to, it will go to a 404 page.

How can I correct this so that I am getting accurate analytics?  See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Basically anybody who has your Google Account ID can send data to your account. This works the same way as referral spam (which seems to be what you are referring to re/ your research). You can set a filter, but I'm afraid you won't be able to remove the wrong data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The weird thing with this is that when I look at referral traffic, sharebutton.to is nowhere to be seen

Comment: I do not think this is strange. It is entirely possible to send a faked pageview without a referrer. And since apparently Google cracked down on referral spam (haven't seen any for quite a while now) "document path spam" might become the next evil thing.

Answer (score 4):

The site sends fake traffic to your website, just to increase its own google page rank.

*sharebutton.to referrer spam is designed to create repeated site requests to the website it lands on. The benefits that referral spammers have with this tactic is that it will help them advertise the website they want people to visit and it will also improve the spammers search engine ranking.*

Solution:
**Add a filter in google analytics to remove the traffic from your reports.**
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034842?hl=en

Comment: So does this mean that the /sharebutton.to page view analytics is just spam and not actual traffic to my site?

Comment: Correct @dps19001, someone probably sent spam traffic to that url.